# Will declaration of array outside a function increase the performance of repeatedly calls to the function?

Tags: function, delphi

```delphi
function MyFunc(const Value: Integer): Integer;
const
  MyArray: array[0..255] of Byte = ( ... ); // values of the array here

begin
  ... // Some codes here
  Result := Integer(MyArray[Value shr 58]);
end;
```

Will declare `MyArray` outside `MyFunc` increases the performance of repeatedly calls to `MyFunc`?

Comment: Why don't you test it and show us the results, if there's any difference? :-)

Comment: @KromStern - Indeed the code looks into a certain memory location, but in which scope? Same performance in my computer is not necessarily the same performance in other computers, so a theory is.needed here. However, David has shown theoritically and practically that "inside/outside" doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will declare `MyArray` outside `MyFunc` increases the performance of repeatedly calls to MyFunc?

No. The compiler will produce identical code no matter if `MyArray` is local to the function, or a constant at a wider scope. Typed constants are stored in the data segment of the executable, irrespective of their scope.